# PySpark UDF to Pandas UDF for sting columns

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, user-defined-functions, pandas-udf

I do have an UDF that is slow for large dataset and I try to improve execution time and scalability by leveraging [pandas_udfs](https://databricks.com/blog/2017/10/30/introducing-vectorized-udfs-for-pyspark.html) and all searching and official documentation does more focus to scalar and a mapping approach that I already used but I do fail to extend to series or pandas dataframe approach, can u point me to right direction ?

I do want to do in parallel and current UDF approach is very slow since is doing sequentially one by one record and other solution I do have is in koalas but I rather include it as part of a custom transformer in pyspark pipeline:

> below listed UDF approach (working one):

```
from pyspark import keyword_only
from pyspark.ml import Transformer
from pyspark.ml.param.shared import HasInputCol, HasOutputCol, Param, Params, TypeConverters
from pyspark.ml.util import DefaultParamsReadable, DefaultParamsWritable
from pyspark.sql import DataFrame
from pyspark.sql.types import ArrayType, StringType
import pyspark.sql.functions as F
from pyspark.sql.functions import PandasUDFType
from pyspark.sql.functions import pandas_udf
from pyspark.sql.functions import udf
from pyspark.sql.types import *

def ngrams_udf(string, n=3):
    """Takes an input string, cleans it and converts to ngrams. 
    This script is focussed on cleaning UK company names but can be made generic by removing lines below"""
    string = str(string)
    string = string.lower() # lower case
    string = string.encode("ascii", errors="ignore").decode() #remove non ascii chars
    chars_to_remove = [")","(",".","|","[","]","{","}","'","-"]
    rx = '[' + re.escape(''.join(chars_to_remove)) + ']' #remove punc, brackets etc...
    string = re.sub(rx, '', string)
    string = string.replace('&', 'and')
    string = string.replace('limited', 'ltd')
    string = string.replace('public limited company', 'plc')
    string = string.replace('united states of america', 'usa')
    string = string.replace('community interest company', 'cic')
    string = string.title() # normalise case - capital at start of each word
    string = re.sub(' +',' ',string).strip() # get rid of multiple spaces and replace with a single
    string = ' '+ string +' ' # pad names for ngrams...
    ngrams = zip(*[string[i:] for i in range(n)])
    return [''.join(ngram) for ngram in ngrams]
    
    # # register UDF
    dummy_ngram_udf = udf(ngrams_udf, ArrayType(StringType()))
    
    # # call udf on string column and returns array type. 
    df.withColumn(out_col, dummy_ngram_udf(col(in_col)))
```

I tried with following but does not map to series the input and output ... so the input vector and output vector has different sizes ...:

```
from pandas import Series
import pandas as pd
from pyspark.sql.functions import col, pandas_udf, struct

@pandas_udf("string")
def ngrams_udf(string: pd.Series , n=3) -> pd.Series:
    """Takes an input string, cleans it and converts to ngrams. 
    This script is focussed on cleaning UK company names but can be made generic by removing lines below"""
    string = str(string)
    string = string.lower() # lower case
    string = string.encode("ascii", errors="ignore").decode() #remove non ascii chars
    chars_to_remove = [")","(",".","|","[","]","{","}","'","-"]
    rx = '[' + re.escape(''.join(chars_to_remove)) + ']' #remove punc, brackets etc...
    string = re.sub(rx, '', string)
    string = string.replace('&', 'and')
    string = string.replace('limited', 'ltd')
    string = string.replace('public limited company', 'plc')
    string = string.replace('united states of america', 'usa')
    string = string.replace('community interest company', 'cic')
    string = string.title() # normalise case - capital at start of each word
    string = re.sub(' +',' ',string).strip() # get rid of multiple spaces and replace with a single
    string = ' '+ string +' ' # pad names for ngrams...
    ngrams = zip(*[string[i:] for i in range(n)])
    return [''.join(ngram) for ngram in ngrams]
```

Comment: Why not using Spark builtin functions? I can be mistaken but all you do here is string manipulations which can be done using spark string functions

Comment: I do have more functions for string manipulation so would be more comfortable for me to do it in python for "portability" so users can understand easier what is all about without learning pyspark (transition is harder from pure pandas).

Answer (score 1):

In general, try to avoid using python UDFs when you can actually do the same thing using only Spark builtin functions.
Although pandas_udf brings better performances, using native spark functions should "*always*" perform faster.

Now for your question, the pandas_udf takes a `pd.Series` so you need to adapt the code as your variable `string` is no longer a single string but a Series.

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as F

@F.pandas_udf(ArrayType(StringType()))
def ngrams_udf(string: pd.Series, n: pd.Series) -> pd.Series:
   """Takes an input string, cleans it and converts to ngrams.
   This script is focussed on cleaning UK company names but can be made generic by removing lines below"""

   n = n.iloc[0]
   string.str.lower()  # lower case
   string.str.encode("ascii", errors="ignore").str.decode("utf8")  # remove non ascii chars

   chars_to_remove = [")", "(", ".", "|", "[", "]", "{", "}", "'", "-"]
   rx = '[' + re.escape(''.join(chars_to_remove)) + ']'  # remove punc, brackets etc...
   string = string.str.replace(rx, '', regex=True)

   string = string.str.replace('&', 'and')
   string = string.str.replace('limited', 'ltd')
   string = string.str.replace('public limited company', 'plc')
   string = string.str.replace('united states of america', 'usa')
   string = string.str.replace('community interest company', 'cic')
   string = string.str.title()  # normalise case - capital at start of each word

   # get rid of multiple spaces and replace with a single
   string = string.str.replace(r"\s+", '', regex=True).str.strip()

   string = string.str.pad(width=1, side='both')  # pad names for ngrams...

   string = string.apply(lambda x: zip(*[x[i:] for i in range(n)]))
   string = string.apply(lambda x: [''.join(ngram) for ngram in list(x)])

   return string
```

And using it with:

```
df.withColumn("ngrams", ngrams_udf(F.col("company"), F.lit(3)))
```

Comment: koalas a.k.a pandas_on_spark does use a lot of pandas udfs and simple UDFs so I try to keep all in same "area" so won't confuse user on why those apply() or map() work with koalas but on the pure pyspark need rewriting entire functions ... This example is the one that most of documentation is missing and as helps me more understanding the approach would open more contribution from community on implamenting more compatibility with pandas API on pySpark.